# Cost of multiple push operations in a stack?

Tags: data-structures, stack

I have a stack and I do some push operations on that.Now we know that a push operation is O(1) generally.So if our stack has a size enough to acomodate 20 elements and we perform push operation 20 times,then what is the cost of the 20 push operations?Is it still gonna be O(1) or the way I think is gonna be n*O(1) = O(n)?

Comment: `O(n)`. The/a term that grows ("as n approaches infinity.."; or 1..20 times in this example) has to be on the inside to make sense when discussing growth. If the term could be moved out then a repeated sequence could be argued to take constant time..

Comment: Now, if `n` *cannot* grow more than 20 (ie. "n does not 'really grow'") it could be rewritten as a constant; then one needs to find another term to make `O(..)` meaningful.

Comment: Ahh, that was a bit misleading at the end of the first comment. Only a *constant* can be pulled out of `O(..)` as it is then outside of the 'function'. So pulling out the `n` "cheats" the definition. It's `O(n)` (term must be inside), not `n * O(1)` (as n is not a constant, usually C).

Comment: @user2864740 Hey thanks!Can you explain your the part of your sentence "If the term could be moved out then a repeated sequence could be argued to take constant time.." ?

Comment: Because then it ("some value of n") would be implicitly a constant. And the entire point of Big-O is to describe limits when some term increases.. and the form reflects this.

Comment: @user2864740 okay!So can I say even though an operation takes O(1),doing it multiples times in the end results in a O(n) operation?

Comment: Basically, yes. With the implicit assertion that n grows without bound. (If it was only done 2 times - a constant - it would still be O(1)).

Comment: @user2864740 okay got it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of pushes at compile time, the time complexity will be of the order of O(1).
If the number of pushes gets its value after the execution and it depends on the data and processing, the time complexity will be of the order of O(n).
It seems unfair but the idea is if it remains the same in different executions of a program, it is a constant while if it depends on the data and varies in different execution of a program, it is non-constant.